# ConcurrentModificationException when iterate through List

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have a private class variable, it's declared as

```
private List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
```

My application throws `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` when multiple threads are trying to iterate through the list

```
for (Iterator i = list.iterator();  i.hasNext(); ){
    System.out.println(i.next()+"\n");
}
```

I'm looking for advises to avoid this issue with minimal changes. This class variable is shared and used by multiple methods in this class.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using an `iterator` on a `Collection`, you must use `iterator.remove()` and not `Collection.remove()` to prevent the `ConcurrentModificationException`. However, if you have multiple threads you may need to use `Collections.syncrhonizedList()` as well.

From the Oracle Java Docs:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());
  ...
synchronized (list) {
    Iterator i = list.iterator(); // Must be in synchronized block
    while (i.hasNext())
        foo(i.next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think I gave the wrong direction. So the desired scenario is when multiple threads access this class, each of them use the list for storing and retrieving their own calculations. Currently private List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>(); will place the list in the heap that's shared by multiple thread. I would like each of the thread has its own copy of the list.  But we are getting the ConcurrentModificationException exception with the current implementation.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by each thread has its own copy of the list. When one thread stores something new should it be updated in the other threads?

Comment: Each thread will store different results in this list (because another method in this class is invoked by each thread that will initialize the list with new ArrrayList again) We want to make this class variable local to each thread instead of shared across multiple threads.

Comment: @enfany If you modifiying the list in anyway while iterating over the list, look at `ListIterator`. You cannot call `list.add()` or `list.remove()` or anything that will change the number of elements in the list directly. You must use `ListIterator` to add/remove elements.

Comment: My question now is actually how to make this variable (List<String> List) as local to each thread? Move it from heap to stack? so it's private to each thread.

Comment: @enfany Why don't you put it into the class that extends `Runnable`? Post your thread class so I can have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can try CopyOnWriteList, JavaDocs say:

> This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException.

```
 List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Comment: If most of the activity are write, do we have alternative structure to ensure thread-safe as well as avoid concurrentmodification exception?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already a clue that, the list is going to be accessed by multiple thread, declare a thread safe `List`.

```
List<String> list= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Given the javadocs sounds like the OP will need to also explicitly synchronize using the synchronized keyword. So just changing the variable to leverage Collections.synchronizedList may not be just enough.